# textFieldShouldEndEditing not firing unless keyboard done key used to go to next uitextfield

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

so i have a problem where i have two uitextfields.  i have delegate in header file.

i find that if a user uses their finger to go from the field 1 directly to field 2 that textFieldShouldEndEditing doesn't fire.  it immediately goes to the 2nd field's textFieldShouldBeginEditing.  can anyone tell me how to catch exiting field 1 if you dont use the keyboard?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do the same as what you would do in `textFieldShouldEndEditing`:

Check what text field is currently the first responder.

Check if the user is allowed to leave the current text field or not.

If not then return NO from `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`.

Comment: if i hear you correctly you are confirming that going from one uitextfield directly to another uitextfield with a finger gesture doesnt trigger anything in the first field your exiting?